passport-facebook /callback opens new tab in safari instead of using current tab
I use passport-faceebook in nestjs application and have a controller in it with /callback route.
After I doing some authenticating stuff I call redirect to client home page. Google-strategy do everything in the same tab (safari and chrome). But Facebook-strategy leave two tabs after authenticating. I expect only home page tab and not need auth page to be left.
In chrome facebook-strategy redirects in one tab as expected.
This behavior only in safari.
All browsers were updated up to last versions.
@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
    constructor(
        private authService: AuthService,
        private cookiesService: CookiesService,
    ) { }

    @Get('facebook')
    @UseGuards(FacebookAuthGuard)
    fbAuth() {}

    @Get('facebook/callback')
    @UseGuards(FacebookAuthGuard)
    async fbAuthCallback(
        @Req() req: Request,
        @Res() res: Response,
        @Query('state') state: string,

    ) {
        const {
            accessToken,
            refreshToken,
        } = await this.authService.authWithProvider(req.user as CreateUserDto);

        this.cookiesService.setAccessTokenCookie(res, accessToken);
        this.cookiesService.setRefreshTokenCookie(res, refreshToken);

        const { origin } = JSON.parse(state);
        res.redirect(`${process.env.CLIENT_URL}${origin || ''}`);
    }

    @UseGuards(GoogleAuthGuard)
    @Get('google')
    googleAuth() { }

    @UseGuards(GoogleAuthGuard)
    @Get('google/callback')
    async googleAuthCallback(
        @Req() req: Request,
        @Res() res: Response,
        @Query('state') state: string,
    ) {
        const {
            accessToken,
            refreshToken,
        } = await this.authService.authWithProvider(req.user as CreateUserDto);

        this.cookiesService.setAccessTokenCookie(res, accessToken);
        this.cookiesService.setRefreshTokenCookie(res, refreshToken);

        const { origin } = JSON.parse(state);
        res.redirect(`${process.env.CLIENT_URL}${origin || ''}`);
    }
}

Expect to have one tab after auth in safari with facebook-pasport
tried to change client side request (using nextjs router from "next/navigation")
router.push(`${process.env.API_URL}/auth/facebook?origin=${encodeURIComponent(path || '')}`);

window.open(`${process.env.API_URL}/auth/facebook?origin=${encodeURIComponent(path || '')}`, '_self');


problem was appeared if tab is pinned in safari probably a safari bug
